# How could I create a function with a completion handler in React-native?

Tags: react-native, cross-platform, reactive-programming

I am trying to use a completion handler in react-native is that possible? 
pls some samples will help.
Thanks.

So i am calling this method in an instance class from a parent class, but want the method to return a value when done.
Right now its returns before the value is created but would rather like for the value to be passed once created.

```
getfcmToken() {
   //generate token here
   firebase.messaging().getToken().then(token => {
       if (token) {
           console.log("LOG: ", token);
           _userID = token
           alert(_userID)
        } else {
            // user doesn't have a device token yet
        }
    })
    return this._userID;
}
```

Comment: You mean like a callback system? If yes; yeah you can, but a callback on completing what exactly?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just send a function as a parameter to getfcmToken. For example:

in helper/ instance class

```
getfcmToken(callback) {
   firebase.messaging().getToken().then(token => {
       if (token) {           
           this._userID = token;
           callback({success: true, token: token};
        } else {
            // user doesn't have a device token yet
            callback({success: false, message: 'User doesn't have device token'});
        }
    });
}
```

and then in parent class:

```
getUserToken() {
   firebaseHelper.getfcmToken((result)=>{
     if (success === true) {
       //do something with token
     }
   });
}
```